# Object Scatter not placing on the surface, any solutions that places it on the surface?

Tags: objects, add-on, surface-deform, scatter-objects-addon

Recently, I have been working with placing down objects, including candy canes and rocks, with the Object Scatter Blender Plugin. However, I have found that the scattered duplicator (the triangles) would be placed on the surface. On the other hand, the instances of the objects (The rocks and the candies) would be placed above the surface, with no certain offset. I am experiencing this issue through three different imported models. When I used this with a candy cane model, it worked. However, I am unsure the reason behind this when I followed the same instructions.

[image]

This looks like when I tried placing these candies on the ground. While the duplicator is on the ground, the actual instances are way above the surface.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you make sure that the origin of the object is at its geometry?

Comment: this worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the origin of the object at its geometry